# java.lang.NullPointerException com.google.android.gms.analytics.w$b.run

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

Has anyone ever seen this exception on Android? I am starting to get a few reports from users on crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException     
com.google.android.gms.analytics.w$b.run        
java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run (Timer.java:284)
```

Thanks.

Comment: search for "java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run (Timer.java:284)", quite a few results at google.

Comment: I did see that but I didn't see anything related to `com.google.android.gms.analytics`.

Comment: If possible, can you provide more call stack? What version of Google Play Services are you using?

Comment: That is all I get on the crashlytics report which might make sense since that Timer is probably on its own thread.

Comment: Here the same, with the same trace and the same error. 
We are using an old Play Service version: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.87'